# Continue A Word

Tags: php

I need help this code:

```
<?php
$keyword = "pie is great";
if ($keyword == "pie is great"){
    echo "Cool :D";
}
?>
```

Now image if there was two text boxes on a form one of them had `pie is` , the other had `great`, how would i check if the sentence was completed to `pie is great`?

like etc, just check if the sentence was completed on 2 different text boxes,

Comment: Your quoted strings aren't even correct. How are we to take this seriously?

Comment: You're missing a quote in the declaration for `$keyword`; it should be `$keyword = "pie is great";`

Comment: Is the sentence known to your code? i.e. will it always be "pie is great", or will there be a third request param with the full sentence? or do you need it to just be *any* valid english sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```
if ($input1 == 'pie is' && $input2 == 'great')
  echo "I like pie too!";
```

Concatenating them will not verify that the 2nd input is 'great' as it might have 'pie is great' in the first input and an empty 2nd input.

Comment: I need to also be like whatever the user submits like pie, then is great or pie then is great, like with whatever combinations

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate both textbox values.

```
<?php
$keyword = "pie is great";
$newVal = $_POST['txtbox1'] . ' ' . $_POST['txtbox2'];
if ($keyword == $newVal)
{
    echo "Cool :D";
}
?>
```

Comment: I need it do that for any other combinations automatically

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you are saying if I am not mistaken is that you want no matter what order the words come in to compare them. Well took a few minutes to write a little code out and this is what I came up with.

```
<?php

$string1 = 'pie is great';

$user_input = $_POST['txtbox1'].' '.$_POST['textbox2'];

$user_input = explode(' ', $user_input);


$sorted = NULL;
foreach($user_input as $row)
{
    if($row === 'pie')
    {
        $sorted .= $row.' ';
    }
}
foreach($user_input as $row)
{
        if($row === 'is')
        {
            $sorted .= $row.' ';
        }
}
foreach($user_input as $row)
{
            if($row === 'great')
            {
                $sorted .= $row;
            }
}

if($sorted == $string1)
{
    // do something
}else{
    // do something else
}
?>
```

All i did was take the input and explode it to make it an array and then loop through to find each word. This is by no means the best way to do this. It is just an example of a possible solution. I tested it to ensure it works and it does no matter what way the words are input.